# logback not printing method name

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j

using logback classic in java app but %M or %method prints a '?' instead of method name. anyone has an idea ? here is the pattern

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level %thread %mdc{X-CorrelationId} %logger %method - %msg%n
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **SMTP appender** or **ASYNC appender**, then you should know about **"includeCallerData"** property. This property is set to false because retrieving caller data is very expensive. Hence things like line number or method name are not retrieved by default.
In your case method name gets replaced by a **CallerData.NA** which is basically **?**

So, add this line to your logback.xml

> <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>

Answer (score 1):

logback emits [`?`](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/c2dcbfcfb4048d11d7e81cd9220efbaaccf931fa/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/CallerData.java#L32) instead of the method name only when the [method name could not be determined](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/c2dcbfc/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/pattern/MethodOfCallerConverter.java#L26). Assuming this is a non-production app, make sure to enable debug symbols for the method name to appear for `%m`.

Comment: I tried building with -g but did not work. However if i set     includeCallerData: true, then i am able to see the method name, but this was only after extensive searching. don't know if it is really needed